# Thymeleaf layout doesn't work

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a layout like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>


    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css}"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/css/main.css}"/>
<title layout:title-patern="$LAYOUT_TITLE - $CONTENT_TITLE">System</title>
</head>
<body>
    <th:block th:replace="fragments/header :: header"/>
    <div class="container">
        <th:block layout:fragment="content"/>
    </div>
    <th:block th:replace="fragments/footer :: footer"/>
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to use it for my index page that looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      layout:decorate="~{fragments/layout}">
<head>
<title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
<div layout:fragment="content" th:remove="tag">
    <h1> Please login</h1>

    <ul>
        <li>Click here <a href="/user" th:href="@{/user}">to login</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

But it just isn't working, bootstrap and css files are not used by the index page, neither is the footer and the header.
I use thymeleaf-layout-dialect 2.2.2
What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by adding

```
<thymeleaf.version>3.0.9.RELEASE</thymeleaf.version>
```

to my pom.xml file under properties